# AppleScript to Launch 1Password mini

Tags: macos, applescript

I use `1Password` to store my passwords, and `fluid.app` to create a few site-specific apps/browsers

While `1Password` integrates well with Chrome, Safari and other browsers, it doesn't play nicely with Fluid apps, which is where my troubles lie.

I have therefore created a shortcut (with `Keyboard Maestro`) to run an applescript to open the mini, when I am in Fluid apps. However, I can't seem to get the applescript to launch the mini. Here are my attempts:

1. `tell application "1Password mini" to launch` does nothing, though AppleScriptEditor doesn't report any errors
2. `tell application "1Password mini" to open` nothing, though AppleScriptEditor doesn't report any errors
3. `tell application "1Password mini" to activate` is pointless, as `1Password mini` is already activated
4. `tell application "1Password" to open` opens the main `1Password` application, not the mini, which is what I need.

Interestingly, when I run (1), (2), and (3), `AppleScriptEditor` automatically replaces `1Password mini` with `2BUA8C4S2C.com.agilebits.onepassword-osx-helper`, which doesn't clarify things for me at all.

Does anybody have any clue how this can be solved?
I'm on OSX 10.10.2 (Yosemite), if it matters

Comment: To whomever voted to close this as off-topic ("general computing and software"), this is a very specific problem about AppleScript code. I have included my attempted code, explained the observed and desired behaviors and have articulated exactly what I'm looking for. I am not asking for software recommendations, but for ways to fix my code to do something specific. Please explain to me where I went wrong, so that I can refrain from a similar error in the future

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*I work for AgileBits, the developer of 1Password.*

Looks like you found a solution, but here's another option for you:

```
open location "x-onepassword-helper://search/"
```

That AppleScript will open 1Password mini ready to search.

And if you're able to get the current website's domain from Fluid, you could even open 1Password Mini with a search term already filled in:

```
open location "x-onepassword-helper://search/twitter.com"
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: from the OSX Terminal `open "x-onepassword-helper://search/twitter.com"` works well too

Answer (score 1):

The solution was quite simple, with a little UI scripting:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "1Password mini"
    tell menu bar item 1 of menu bar 1 to click
end tell
```