# How to copy the contents of a password from 1Password using applescript ?

Tags: macos, applescript

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29597515/5771861) mentions how to launch 1Password mini and select a password from an applescript. As a follow-up how can one copy the contents of the password to the clipboard? What should the command be in the applescript ?

Comment: @AgileBits_Jasper Since you have answered the linked question, do you also know how to send CMD+C to 1Password ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1Password Mini doesn't appear to have an API, so we have to kludge our way through it.

Here's one approach:

```
set theSearchTerm to "facebook"

-- Search for the password in 1Password
do shell script "open x-onepassword-helper://search/" & theSearchTerm

delay 0.5

-- Copy to clipboard
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "c" using {shift down, command down}

delay 0.5

-- Ensure password is copied as pasteable text
do shell script "pbpaste | pbcopy"

-- Use the password
set thePassword to (the clipboard as text)
```

There are a couple of issues to be aware of:

1. You are copying a password to the clipboard as plain text, and due to the `"pbpaste | pbcopy"` line the text will not auto-delete after 90 seconds. (I couldn't get my script to work without this step)
2. If the search term does not return any results, you will get an AppleScript error

Here is a different approach that handles 1Password not returning any search results. Since there doesn't appear to be any way to parse the 1Password search results (I'd love to hear if anyone has a way to do this), I have implemented a second kludge: check the clipboard to see if it has been modified. If no search result, the clipboard contents will not change. If there is a search result, the clipboard content will be different, assuming you don't use the same password over and over!

```
set theSearchTerm to "foo"
set thePassword to ""

-- Search for the password in 1Password
open location "x-onepassword-helper://search/" & theSearchTerm

delay 0.5

tell application "System Events" to tell process "1Password mini"

    set theClipboardTextPre to (the clipboard as text)

    -- Copy to clipboard
    keystroke "c" using {shift down, command down}
    delay 0.5

    -- Ensure password is copied as pasteable text
    do shell script "pbpaste | pbcopy"

    -- Check to see if clipboard contents have changed
    -- If no change, it implies 1Password didn't return a search result
    set theClipboardTextPost to (the clipboard as text)

    if theClipboardTextPre is not equal to theClipboardTextPost then
        set thePassword to theClipboardTextPost
    end if

end tell

log thePassword
```

The drawback here is that if you have two sites using identical passwords the script will think 1Password did not return a search result.

Comment: Excellent Thank you.